# Parsing date string using SimpleDateFormat with Wildcard support (e.g. *yyyy*MM*dd*hh*mm*ss)

Tags: java, wildcard, simpledateformat

First of all, I'd like to know if there is an existing library that is similar to **SimpleDateFormat** but supports wildcard characters? If not, what is the best approach for this?

I have this problem where I need to match and extract the date from a file name but I could not seem to find the right approach for this scenario. While I admit that the scenario below isn't practical at all for a file name, I've had to include it still as a "WHAT IF".

## **Scenario**

**Filename**: 19882012ABCseptemberDEF03HIJ12KLM0156_249.zip, **Pattern**: *yyyy*MMM*dd*hh*mmss'_*.zip'

- **Expected Date:** September 03, 2012 12:01:56 AM
- **Broken down version:** 1988-2012-ABC-september-DEF-03-HIJ-12-KLM-01-56-_249.zip

I see a lot of issues parsing this (e.g. determining the correct year).  I hope you guys can shed some light and help me get to the right direction.

Comment: I hardly think that it's possible. Could you give any reason why "2012" is preferred in your example over "1988"? Both look like 4-digit year even to me, a human.

Comment: Also, your original pattern includes `'` (tick character). What does it stand for? It doesn't seem that it's included in parsed filename and even "broken down version".

Comment: 1988 is just a random number that does not pertain to a year. Its the actual value that replaces first wildcard character. I used this example instead because a wildcard can be any character..if the input was a 4 digit number, then it would be difficult to determine the correct year.

Comment: The tick character represents a fixed string, this is already supported by the SimpleDateFormat class, but currently does not support a wildcard character.

Comment: Ok, but how does one determines if `1988` is "just a random number", while `2012` is a valid value that represents a year. Do you have a range/list of valid years or something like that?

Comment: I think a regex might be your only recourse...

Comment: I agree a regex replace before a call to parse is what you want.

Comment: well that is where I am stuck at...no list of valid years or whatsoever. All I have is a defined pattern and the file name. Also, take note that we do not have control over the filename since these files come from a third party source.

Comment: @RaffyIbasco You should ask the third party how to make sense of their format and what each part means. They can't exactly turn around and say; our formats make no sense. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no sunch thing that I know of in `SimpleDateFormat` but what you can do is check with a regular expression if the input filename match, and if it does extract what matched to create your date.

This is a quick regex that validates your criterias:

`(.*?)([0-9]{4})([^0-9]*?)([a-z]+)(.*?)([0-9]{2})(.*?)([0-9]{2})(.*?)([0-9]{4})_([^.]+)[.]zip`

Which means (it's really not that complicated)

```
(.*?) // anything 
([0-9]{4}) // followed by 4 digits
([^0-9]*?) // followed by anything excepted digits
([a-z]+) // followed by a sequence of text in lowercase
(.*?) // followed by anything
([0-9]{2}) // until it finds 2 digits
(.*?) // followed by anything
([0-9]{2}) // until it finds 2 digits again
(.*?) // followed by anything
([0-9]{4}) // until if finds 4 consecutive digits
_([^.]+) // an underscore followed by anything except a dot '.'
[.]zip // the file extension
```

You can use it in Java

```
String filename = "19882012ABCseptemberDEF03HIJ12KLM0156_249.zip";
String regex = "(.*?)([0-9]{4})([^0-9]*?)([a-z]+)(.*?)([0-9]{2})(.*?)([0-9]{2})(.*?)([0-9]{4})_([^.]+)[.]zip";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(filename);
if (m.matches()) {
    // m.group(2); // the year
    // m.group(4); // the month
    // m.group(6); // the day
    // m.group(8); // the hour
    // m.group(10); // the minutes & seconds
    String dateString = m.group(2) + "-" + m.group(4) + "-" + m.group(6) + " " + m.group(8) + m.group(10);
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HHmmss").parse(dateString);
    // here you go with your date
}
```

Runnable sample on ideone: http://ideone.com/GBDEJ

Edit: 
you can avoid matching what you dont wan't by removing the parenthesis around what you dont care. Then the regular expression becomes `.*?([0-9]{4})[^0-9]*?([a-z]+).*?([0-9]{2}).*?([0-9]{2}).*?([0-9]{4})_[^.]+[.]zip` and the matched group becomes

```
group(1): the year
group(2): the month
group(3): the day
group(4): the hour
group(5): the minutes & secondes
```